# Cloning a website to train with CSS

Tags: css, border

I'm copying a website to train with CSS (I'm trying to reproduce this:[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IOSe.png)) but I'm having a problem copying borders, this is the result: [click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc7nP.png)  and this is the code that I wrote:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Technology - BBC News</title>
  <style>
    .topbar {
      width: 1000px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    
    .logo {
      margin-top: 8px;
      width: 100px;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 16px;
    }
    
    .topbar-section {
      border-left: 1px solid grey;
      height: 40px;
      float: left,
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="topbar">
    <img src="bbc-blocks-dark.png" class="logo"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="topbar-section">Sign in</div>

</body>

</html>
```

May I have your help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I look at this code in Chrome - I can see the left border on .topbar-section.

When you say you are having problems - can you tell us what is happening? Are they not showing, or showing incorrectly?

From what I can see - the main problem is that you have made 2 separate divs where it should be one div inside another.

You've also got 3 closing  and only 2 opening  - if you are using an editor such as Atom or Notepad++ this can help you keep track of your opening and closing elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Technology - BBC News</title>
  <style>
    .topbar {
      width: 1000px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
    }

    .logo {
      margin-top: 8px;
      width: 100px;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 16px;
      border-right: 1px solid grey;

    }

    .topbar-section {
      height: 40px;
      float: left;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }


  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="topbar">
    <img src="bbc-blocks-dark.png" class="logo">


  <div class="topbar-section"><p>Sign In</p></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The boarder should be displayed like in the image that I added, but it's showing incorrectly.

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't understand - can you share a screenshot?

Comment: I added it now.

Comment: I've added some code now, which I think is what you are looking for - you just need to play around with different things until you work out what you need...

Comment: I don't get it, I floated everything but It's not working. The code should be the same that the teacher wrote.

Comment: The code I posted above works for me - if you are struggling to get it working I would suggest asking your teacher...

Comment: You were right, the problem was that I created two main divs, I did like you wrote and then I put a border in the .topbar-section (it had to be in that div not in the BBC), thank you very much!